# How to bind complex forms using Spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, forms, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, data-binding

I'm building a webApp using Spring MVC, and I'm facing a medium difficulty task. I have to bind a complex form with multiple attributes each attribute might have multiple parameters ... etc.

I've done the form cloning with the Jquery pluging Sheepit :

> Example :
>   http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB&sec=demo7

And now I'm wondering if it exists any manner in Spring MVC to bind dynamically these forms and persist them using hibernate... What is the best approach ?

Comment: I am curious about the approach you've achieved so far. It seems an interesting thing.

Comment: Since I didn't receive any answer, I changed My approach, I gave Knockoutjs a try, now I can clone my forms dynamically and send the result as a JSON String to my Spring MVC Controller, and then parse the result Using Jackson ...